# C++ standard conforming method to assign address of program memory to pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to assing internal process memory address to pointer object in C++ via standard conforming method?

For example, this is Undefined behavior, coz its dont defined in C++ Standard:

```
CInterpretator* pInterpretatorObj= reinterpret_cast<CInterpretator*>(0x1000FFFF);
```

or this, without reinterpret_cast, but with same effect:

```
CInterpretator* pInterpretatorObj= static_cast<CInterpretator*>(static_cast<void*>(0x1000FFFF));
```

Maybe using .asm file with public function who return address of object, and using this "foreign" function in C++ program code for get address is standard conforming or not?

But for me its very ugly. Maybe there are good methods for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standards-compliant way of doing this. Standard C++ does not have a notion of memory layout, nor of particular integers being meaningful when casted to pointers (other than those which came from casting pointers to integers).

The good news is, “undefined behavior” is undefined *by the standard*. Implementations are free to offer guarantees that certain types of otherwise-UB code will do something meaningful. So if you want guaranteed correctness, rather than “just happened to work”, you won’t get that from the Standard but you may get it from your compiler documentation.

For literally all C++ compilers I know of, using `reinterpret_cast` as you’ve done here will do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks! Last question: I agree that the standard doesn't define this. If we use reinterpret_cast, then the compiler gives guarantees that we will get a pointer as a result, BUT! Compiler and C++ standard doesn't guarantee that the address is received by standard conformig way. C++ abstract machine doesn't see this object. BUT! If using a external API, for example .asm file with function CTest* get_address(uint), we get pointer, and this is standard conforming way for abstract machine. And we delegate guarantees from compiler, and C++ Standard to external API. This is correct? Or not?

Comment: No. The standard does not allow for "external APIs". All functions must be defined in C++ translation units.